# Efficient Camel Content Based Router: Route XML messages to the correct recipient based on contained tag with Java DSL

Tags: java, xpath, routes, apache-camel, dsl

**The problem:**

I need to process different huge XML files. Each file contains a certain node which I can use to identify the incoming xml message by. Based on the node/tag the message should be send to a dedicated recipient.

The XML message should not be converted to String and then checked with *contains* as this would be really inefficient. Rather xpath should be used to "probe" the message for the occurrence of the expected node.

The solution should be based on camel's Java DSL. The code:

```
from("queue:foo")
.choice().xpath("//foo")).to("queue:bar") 
.otherwise().to("queue:others");
```

suggested in [Camel's Doc](http://camel.apache.org/xpath.html) does not compile. I am using Apache Camel 2.19.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles:

```
    from("queue:foo")
        .choice().when(xpath("//foo"))
            .to("queue:bar") 
        .otherwise()
            .to("queue:others");
```

You need the .when() to test predicate expressions when building a [content-based-router](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html).

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work, though I also found out that the following syntax has the same satisfactory effect:

`from("queue:foo")
        .choice()
            .when().xpath("//foo").to("queue:bar")
            .when().xpath("//baz").to("queue:bazq")
        .otherwise()
            .to("queue:others");`

Comment: That will work, but I think it's better style to keep your predicate within when() just like you were doing regular Java.  What happens if you need to build a slightly more complicated predicate?  Note that the following in the content-based-router will not compile:  `.choice().when().header("foo").isEqualTo("bar").to("queue:bar")`    But this does:  `choice().when(header("foo").isEqualTo("bar")).to("queue:bar")`